# mysqli return json array from single sql table column

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I am selecting a single column from an SQL table. I want to get as result an array of usernames in json. I don't know what to write in the `missing code` place in the code below.

Desired result for example:

users ["userA", "userB", "userC"];

```
<?php
    require_once 'connection.php';
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT username FROM users");
    $users = array();
    // missing code
    $json = json_encode($users);
    echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: Try change it to `$users = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch all of the users using...

```
$users = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Using `MYSQLI_NUM` will return a numerically indexed list and so `json_encode()` will work as you wish.